# html overflow:hidden within dropdown-menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to solve an overflow problem in my slyding dropdown menu. 
For slyding I'm using the als-js framework. The problem is, if I set the overflow:hidden attribute my dropdown menu is not visibly anymore.
If I just set the overflow-x:hidden I'm getting a scrollbar.

```
<div class="als-container" id="cssmenu"> <span class="als-prev"><img src="back.png" alt="back" title="previous" /></span>

<div class="als-viewport">
    <ul class="als-wrapper">
        <li class='als-item active'><a href='index.html'>Home</a>

            <ul>
                <li class='final'><a href='#'>Test 1</a>

                </li>
                <li class='final'><a href='#'>Test 2</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <li class=' als-item has-sub '><a href='#'>Products</a>

                <ul>
                    <li class='final'><a href='#'>Product 1</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class='final'><a href='#'>Product 2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class='final'><a href='#'>Product 2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class='final'><a href='#'>Product 2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class='final'><a href='#'>Product 2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class='final'><a href='#'>Product 2</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="als-item"><a href='#'>About</a>

            </li>
            <li class='als-item active'><a href='index.html'>Admin</a>

            </li>
            <li class='als-item active'><a href='index.html'>Route</a>

            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQUery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#cssmenu").als({
    visible_items: 4,
    scrolling_items: 2,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    circular: "yes",
    autoscroll: "no"
});
});
```

Here is the link to my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/9zapu02q/11/

Perhaps somebody could help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/9zapu02q/12/)**

Your `div.als-viewport` must have a greater height... but you asl script is setting the div height, so you need to use " IMPORTANT " to override the value.

```
.als-viewport {
  height: 300px !IMPORTANT;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. For my real world example this does not work because I have a content area underneath the menu and with this solution the als-viewport is overlaying my content and I can’t access links, buttons…
So perhaps there is another solution providing overflow on the y-axis that the second ul-elments can float out of my als-viewport?

Comment: z-index will not solve your issue ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index)) ... you can set the als-viewport position to absolute and add some margin-top to your content